# java: how to get Timezone abbreviation (from offset)?

Tags: java, time, timezone, abbreviation

My code like belows, I am using android. I found different devices may have different result.

Using different phone: I can get : "EST" or "GMT-05:00".

However, I just want to get abbreviation(just like "EST").

How can I get the abbreviation (or change offset to abbreviation)?

```
   String timezone =Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

Comment: Do you mean the timezone of the default locale? Or of particular ZonedDateTime value?

Comment: The timezone of default locale

Comment: I probably get the answer, The reason the phone can return "GMT-05:00", because the phone change it language to Chinese. So if I change the code to getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT,Locale.US), it will return "EST"

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else need the solution : I just tweak the code and get desired short name, which i needed to display to user.

```
private static String getTimeZoneShortName() {

    String tz = TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName();

    String[] stz = tz.split(" ");

    StringBuilder sName = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < stz.length; i++) {
        sName.append(stz[i].charAt(0));
    }
    return sName.toString();
}
```

Comment: With Kotlin: TimeZone.getDefault().displayName.split(" ").map { it[0] }.joinToString("")

Comment: Tricky solution, but to be honest i'm not recommending that. Abbreviations are not always same as first letters of display name, here you can check list of all abbreviations and compare:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations