# get timezone abbreviation in android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to get Timezone abbreviation for the given Timezone. Here is my code.

```
TimeZone  tz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30");
Log.e("given time zone >>",tz.getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT));
```

But I get in log as GMT+05:30 only, I like to get IST (abbreviation).
What I have done wrong?

Comment: did you google this question? I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984302/java-how-to-get-timezone-abbreviation-from-offset

Comment: Zunjae, it is for default timezone, i like to have for my own timezone.

Comment: There is not a unique abbreviation for every possible offset, so you cannot accomplish this.